# Hover any link then hide certain div

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I summarize my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/marciano/BSzAn/

I have some links

```
<a href="">Some text 1</a>
<a href="">Some text 2</a>
<a href="">Some text 3</a>
<a id="menu" href="">MENU</a>
<a id="submenu" href="">SUBMENU</a>
```

And js

```
$(function() {
      $('#submenu').hide();
      $('#menu').hover( function() { $('#submenu').show(); } );
});
```

When I hover MENU, SUBMENU shows up.

What I need is to hide 'submenu' when I hover any of the other links but 'menu'.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95ufa/)

```
   $(function () {
    $('#submenu').hide();
    $('#menu').hover(function () {
        $('#submenu').show();
    });
    $('a:not(#menu,#submenu)').hover(function () {
        $('#submenu').hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: I little deeper. I want to include in not(#menu....) all links inside a div class="A1". Thanks

Comment: Did not understand completely can you make a fiddle?

Comment: No, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/marciano/BSzAn/8/ . Hover MENU displays div.A1 that contains two link. As expected, mouse over them turn them hidden. I added their ids to a:not(... but I am curious not to have to list them, just to exclude from hide all A1 links content

Comment: Incredible simple! As usual with query. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$('#menu').hover( function() { $('#submenu').show(); }, function() { $('#submenu').hide(); } );
```

Or use this...

```
$('#submenu').hide();
$('#menu').hover( function() { $('#submenu').toggle(); } );
```

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BSzAn/6/)**

Comment: I already had tried something similar but I need to hide 'submenu' ONLY when I hover other the other links